# 404 error on Node.js Azure webapp after a short time

Tags: node.js, azure, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I have an issue on a node.js application running on an Azure webapp. After a random time of execution, the static files are put in error 404. But not all files.
For example, today I have a logo.jpg picture in my public folder public/images/. When the application is freshly started, no problem. But after 1h, sometimes 1 day, the same url will give a 404 error. By restarting the webapp, the problem is corrected for a time. 2nd precision, when I redeploy the missing file with ftp, the error disappeared, just briefly, (1 minute) before reappearing. Is this a cache error? My web.config not set correctly?
Thank you in advance for your help as I have been on this error for many days and I am beginning to lose hope.

Comment: upload your static files to a CDN and just reference them in your node app, Node is not good for serving static files and it's not certainly built for that. It will save you tons of time on "how to get it right on node" but it will still be slower and not scalable.

Comment: @Yousaf - CDN isn't really related to a file that goes missing. And CDN is also not necessarily the solution for static files in Azure (vs, say, blob storage, which is completely independent of web apps, and accessible via URI). And you're making some strong assumptions about node.js and static files.

Comment: Is it possible the machine that hosts those static files suffers from availability issues?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, CDN is absolutely the solution for static files, since is cheap and very easy to implement, If you don't want to implement CDN serve the files through something like varnish or nginx. I am not making strong assumptions about nodes capability for static files I know the all ins and outs of the node to confidently say node sucks and static content and is totally an antipattern. "Node is not designed to serve static content"It's another thing to say yes it can do the job but is it the best solution? "Not at all"

Comment: express.static or koa.send consume cpu time which isn't available for your main app loop until file(s) are sent. In details - express.send cares too much for dynamic stuff like settings response headers, calculating response status, calculating size of files, finding correct mime types, etc, etc, etc. this computing happens on your main app loop but this main loop should be used as much as possible exclusively for your business computations only.

By the way in 2018 are we still having this conversation that node for static content or not ? Please give me a break.

Comment: @Yousaf CDN won't find a missing file (aside from a CDN-cached version being available until TTL expires, assuming the client doesn't request content from another regional CDN node that doesn't already have the content cached). And CDN comes with a cost (might be easy, but might not be cheap). And a CDN isn't something you "upload to" - there needs to be a persistent storage medium. Point being, you're suggesting an optimization unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file in question actually disappears, or is it strictly an access issue? Since you're running on a web app, two things to consider: 1) if you chose a very low tier (e.g. free), you have very limited resources (and daily cpu limits), and 2) do you have always-on enabled? If not, your app pool expires after 20 minutes, and you might see loading issues when visiting your site after this point, temporarily.